# ag-grid header checkbox selection event

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Just want to know whether we can distinguish between all row selection and individual row selection in ag-grid(via header checkbox selection). Is there a method or property associated with ag-grid to tell this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The ag-grid `api` offers some useful methods:

`this.api.getSelectedRows()` will get you all the selected rows.

`this.api.getDisplayedRowCount()` will get you all the rows displayed.

If these 2 equal each other, then the user has selected all the rows.

Ps. the `api` is a of type `GridApi`, which is initialised from the `gridReady` event exposed by `ag-grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Just listen to selectionChanged [event](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/) at grid level to apply some action per selection changed by column header checkbox

Comment: can you prevent selection for some rows?